# JUnit test giving NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception

One of my JUnit tests is giving me a NullPointerException and I can't figure out why.
This is the contents of the test class, PacketWrapperTest:

```
/**
 * Mock Node for Packet A.
 */
private Node nA;

/**
 * Packet A.
 */
private PacketWrapper packetA;

/**
 * Mock Node for Packet B.
 */
private Node nB;

/**
 * Packet B.
 */
private PacketWrapper packetB;

/**
 * Relationship A
 */
Relationship RelA;

/**
 * Relationship B
 */
Relationship RelB;

@Before
public void setup() {
    nA = mock(Node.class);
    nB = mock(Node.class);
    packetA = new PacketWrapper(nA);
    packetB = new PacketWrapper(nB);
    RelA = mock(Relationship.class);
    RelB = mock(Relationship.class);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    packetA = null;
    packetB = null;
}
/*
 * ---------------- Test hashContents() ---------------
 */
@Test
public void testHashContents() {//TODO: Fix
    when(nA.getProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS)).thenReturn(new byte[] {1});
    packetA.hashContents();
    verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode());
    verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.IS_HASH, true);
}
```

This is the relevant contents of PacketWrapperTest:

```
/**
 * DB key for the contents property.
 */
static final String KEY_CONTENTS = "contents";

/**
 * DB key for the is_hashed property.
 */
static final String IS_HASH = "is_hashed";

/**
 * Underlying neo4j node.
 */
private final Node neo4jNode;

/**
 * Creates a new Packet wrapping the specified node
 * 
 * @param neo4jNode
 *            underlying neo4j node.
 */
public PacketWrapper(Node neo4jnode) {
    this.neo4jNode = neo4jnode;
}

@Override
public byte[] getContents() {
    return (byte []) neo4jNode.getProperty(KEY_CONTENTS);
}

@Override
public void setContents(byte[] newContents) {
    neo4jNode.setProperty(KEY_CONTENTS, newContents);
}

@Override
public void hashContents() {
    neo4jNode.setProperty(KEY_CONTENTS, ((byte[])getContents()).hashCode());
    neo4jNode.setProperty(IS_HASH, true);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return neo4jNode.hashCode();
}
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.whispercomm.manes.server.graph.PacketWrapperTest.testHashContents(PacketWrapperTest.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Although Java didn't give me that long of a stack trace for some reason, I only had the first two lines and saw the rest when I copied and pasted...

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to mention line 124 is

```
verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode());
```

Also, I'm using the neo4j libraries.

EDIT2: After adding in some debugging statements this is the test code:

```
@Test
public void testHashContents() {//TODO: Fix
    byte[] testByte = new byte[] {1};
    when(nA.getProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS)).thenReturn(testByte);
    packetA.hashContents();
    System.out.println(testByte.hashCode());
    System.out.println(packetA.getContents());
    System.out.println(packetA.getContents().hashCode());
    verify(nA, times(3)).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode());
    verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.IS_HASH, true);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
26281671
[B@19106c7
26281671
```

The line:

```
verify(nA, times(3)).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode());
```

is throwing the exception.

Comment: soooo which line is 124?

Comment: So what's null? What line is that? And man I hate comments like `/** Packet A */ foo bar packetA;`, I can tell from the name :(

Comment: with the output you added, which line throws the NPE? this question is very hard to follow.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. If I could start over with this question I would, but I can't. The same line: verify(nA, times(3)).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode()); has the NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

```
verify(nA).setProperty(KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode());
```

you are actually calling `hashCode` on `nA` (through delegation) before you are calling `setProperty` which is confusing Mockito as to which method is being verified.  Change your test to

```
    @Test
public void testHashContents() {//TODO: Fix
    when(nA.getProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS)).thenReturn(new byte[] {1});
    packetA.hashContents();
    int hash = packetA.getContents().hashCode();
    verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, hash);
    verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.IS_HASH, true);
}
```

and you will see it passes.

Comment: Sorry, I made the question more clear in the edits.

The fact that the test is failing means the class was worth testing. Unless of course the problem is with my test.

Comment: I think it is your test failing.  Check if packetA.getContents() returns null.

Comment: Take a look at EDIT2 in my post. packetA.getContents() does not return null.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.  That was a stumper.

Comment: Thank you! It works, although I'm still confused why. Why would mockito be confused as to which method is verified? Isn't it clear that it's setProperty()?

Comment: No, verify is a static method that tells mockito that the next method called on the mock nA is the one to verify as having been called.

Answer (score 2):

Line 124 would have to be one of these:

```
when(nA.getProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS)).thenReturn(new byte[] {1});
packetA.getContents().hashCode()
verify(nA).setProperty(PacketWrapper.KEY_CONTENTS, packetA.getContents().hashCode());
```

If verify(nA) or when(...) returns null, then those lines would NPE; if the property `KEY_CONTENTS` is not defined, then the second will throw an NPE. Other lines would give stack traces with other methods on top. There are too many different ways where these things could go wrong, all having to do with other code not shown here; you'll have to track this down yourself.

Comment: I forgot to include the variables defined in PacketWrapper. I've added those in. Hopefully that makes it less ambiguous.